# Como converter uma página .aspx em PDF e anexar no email em VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, itextsharp

Tenho um Link que abre um boleto em uma página .aspx.
Preciso converter esse link em PDF, ou seja, converter o Boleto em PDF e anexá-lo no e-mail que enviarei via VB.
Tentei os passos deste tutorial:
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Generate-Create-PDF-and-send-as-email-attachment-in-ASPNet.aspx

Porém ele explica somente como converter quando o HTML está na mesma página, e eu preciso converter um outro link, que contém o boleto.

Estou utilizando o itextSharp, ASP/VB.NET

Poderiam me ajudar?

Obrigado desde já.

=============================EDIÇÃO=====================================

Tentei de diversas maneiras, essa é a última que tentei:

```
Dim pdfDoc As New Document()
Dim wr As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, New FileStream(pdfPath,   FileMode.Create))
pdfDoc.Open()
pdfDoc.Add(wr)
pdfDoc.Close()
```

A exceção que recebo é essa: Não há suporte para formatos de URI.

Preciso de uma maneira de interpretar a URL e converter o Boleto em PDF, os exemplos que encontrei só mostram como criar um novo PDF a partir do HTML da própria página. =[

Obrigado!

Comment: você não tem ideia de como fazer e nem começou nada?

Comment: Eu nunca fui muito feliz ao usar bibliotecas .NET de conversão de HTML para PDF, então aconselho você dá uma olhada no [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org), você poderá integrar ele a sua aplicação usando o seguinte [wrapper](http://www.nrecosite.com/phantomjs_wrapper_net.aspx), ou usando o [EdgeJS](http://tjanczuk.github.io/edge/#/7) que está disponível no seguinte [nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Edge.js/).

Comment: @RafaelAcioly nunca fiz nada parecido, meu ponto de partida foi o tutorial do link que postei, a parte do e-mail está funcional, a questão é somente a conversão do link e anexar o mesmo no e-mail dependendo de como for salvo.

Comment: @TobyMosque Vou dar uma olhada nisso, obrigado!

Comment: É que normalmente as pessoas podem te ajudar melhor se você já tenha algum trecho de código ou alguma ideia de como fazer isso, a pergunta/post certo seria: "Estou tentando fazer isso deste jeito...como melhorar ou fazer de outro jeito?"

Comment: @RafaelAcioly editei com o trecho que testei agora.